# Swift "switch case" abbreviated syntax

Tags: swift

While reading a tutorial about a deck of card, [here](https://gist.github.com/erica/b849cef7fcd123756373), I found:

```
enum Suit: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
  case Clubs = 1, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades

  var description: String {
    return ["♣️", "♦️", "❤️", "♠️"][rawValue - 1]
  }
}
```

works well in playground. 
I understand it should be a short syntax for:

```
enum Suit: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
  case Clubs = 1, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades

  var description: String {
    switch self {
      case .Spades:
        return "♠️"
      case .Clubs:
        return "♣️"
      case .Diamonds:
        return "♦️"
      case .Hearts:
        return "♥️"
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation on this syntax. Does it have a name or is it described in the official documentation or any other place? Thanks for any contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't any special syntax by itself. It's two separate things:

1. An array literal, `["♣️", "♦️", "❤️", "♠️"]` which is an `Array<String>` a.k.a. `[String]`
2. Array subscripting syntax: `myArray[i]` or, in this case, `array[rawValue - 1]` where `array` is the literal from #1.

`["♣️", "♦️", "❤️", "♠️"][rawValue - 1]` just means the `rawValue - 1`th entry of that array. It relies on the fact that the enum is declared with `enum Suit: Int` so that each value has an underlying `rawValue`.

Answer (score 2):

```
["♣️", "♦️", "❤️", "♠️"][rawValue - 1]
```

is not a special syntax. Here's how it would be broken down:

```
let array: [String] = ["♣️", "♦️", "❤️", "♠️"]
let index: Int = self.rawValue - 1
let symbol = array[index]
return symbol
```